# c# cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to return the referencesModel object but I am getting a error about the type of object. Is there another way to do this?

```
public ActionResult Edit(string index)
{
    var selectedReference = template.References.First(reference => reference.SortOrder == index);
    ReferencesModel referencesModel = selectedReference;
    return PartialView(referencesModel);
}
```

**Error:**
(local variable) Data.Reference selectedReference
Cannot implicitly convert type 'OrderTemplateTool.Data.Reference' to 'OrderTemplateTool.Web.Models.References.RederencesModel"

**Model:**

```
public class ReferencesModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Regimens { get; set; }
    public Guid GuidlineId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's not the same type. You cannot do this. What is it that you *want* to do?

Comment: use a custom converter or [automapper](https://automapper.org/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some constructers to your ReferenceModel class.

```
public class ReferencesModel
{
    public ReferencesModel()
    {

    }

    public ReferencesModel(Reference reference)
    {
        this.Id = reference.Id;
        this.Link = reference.Link;
        this.Text = reference.Text;
        this.Type = reference.Type;
        this.Regimens = reference.Regimens;
        this.GuidlineId = reference.GuidlineId;
        this.SortOrder = reference.SortOrder;
    }


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Regimens { get; set; }
    public Guid GuidlineId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this

```
    public ActionResult Edit(string index)
    {
        var selectedReference = template.References.First(reference => reference.SortOrder == index);
        ReferencesModel referencesModel = new ReferencesModel(selectedReference);
        return PartialView(referencesModel );
    }
```